# command gets stuck for some reason

Tags: c, ip, bit

I am trying to input basic ip address from the user, but my command gets stuck here in the scanf and nothing after that is executed.

```
   int ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4;
   scanf("%d.%d.%d.%d",&ip1,&ip2,&ip3,&ip4);
   printf("Here");
```

So, basically "Here" is never printed and the command scanf never gets over?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void) {
char input;
char rep = 'r';
char quit = 'q';
char first = '1';
char second = '2';
input = rep;
while( input != quit) {
    printf("What type of conversion do you want? \n");
    printf("Enter 1 for 32-bit number to dot-decimal conversion, 2 for the inverse of operation: ");
        char val;
    scanf(" %c", &val);
    if( val == first) {
    } else if( val == second) {
        printf("\nEnter dot-decimal IP address:");

        int ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4;
        scanf(" %d.%d.%d.%d", &ip1,&ip2,&ip3,&ip4);
        printf("Here");
        unsigned int ip = 0,c,k,counter = 31;
        for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
            k = ip1 >> c;
            if(k & 1) {
                int temp = 2,i;
                for(i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
                    temp *= 2;
                }
                ip += temp;
                counter--;
            }

        }

        for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
            k = ip2 >> c;
            if(k & 1) {
                int temp = 2,i;
                for(i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
                    temp *= 2;
                }
                ip += temp;
                counter--;
            }
        }


        for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
            k = ip3 >> c;
            if(k & 1) {
                int temp = 2,i;
                for(i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
                    temp *= 2;
                }
                ip += temp;
                counter--;              
            }
        }   

        for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
            k = ip4 >> c;
            if(k & 1) {
                int temp = 2,i;
                for(i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
                    temp *= 2;
                }
                ip += temp;
                counter--;              
            }
        }


        printf("%u is the IP Address",ip);

    }
    printf("\n \n Enter r to repeat, q to quit:");
    scanf(" %c",&input);
}
return 0;
```

}

This is the exactly what i was doing. It gets stuck on when i try to get the IP Address in decimal notation.

Comment: How are you passing the input?

Comment: 192.162.2.3 (just one case)

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://ideone.com/Lif8Wv

Comment: @dave: Did you feed an Enter key after the input? It works fine for me. You don't have spaces between the digits right?

Comment: By any chance, `./your_command 192.162.2.3` ?

Comment: @dave: it works fine for me.

Comment: No, it has a printf before it for asking the ip. And, yes i press enter after writing the input but it still wouldn't execute any command after that.

Comment: Can it be like a gcc issue? Should i try to restart my terminal?

Comment: @dave - It's not a gcc issue. The link I supplied uses gcc to compile the code. The problem is in something you aren't showing.

Comment: Not using scanf at all may be a solution.

Comment: I just added the code i am using as a whole. if you try running it you'll see it gets struck when i press option 2 and then it's input.

Answer (score 1):

I have analyzed your code after update (full code) and found that problem not in the input with `scanf` but in the `for` loops that are executed after data is obtained.

Look at that loop:

```
    unsigned int ip = 0,c,k,counter = 31;
    for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--) {
        k = ip1 >> c;
        if(k & 1) {
            int temp = 2,i;
            for(i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
                temp *= 2;
            }
            ip += temp;
            counter--;
        }
    }
```

and particularly at `for(c = 7; c >= 0; c--)` taking into account that `c` is of type `unsigned int`... I see that this loop is INFINITE because decrement makes from `0` new positive value `UINT_MAX` (see limits.h).